# Image not rendering on flask - broken image - picture saved in static/images

Tags: python, html, css, image, flask

Im new to flask to please forgive me if this is a simple mistake.

I've built a basic website through flask and I am having issues with images rendering on my pages. It was actually working for a while but doesn't seem to be anymore.

In short, I have a file that scrapes a certain website for data and then plots an image (matplotlib) and then saves it to my images folder within my static folder. I can see the image has plotted and saved correctly to the images folder but when I try and show it on one of my pages then it gives me the dreaded broken image picture (the little thing that looks like a picture that has been ripped in half).

This is the script which retrieves, plots and saves the image

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def scrape(cells):
    cell_contents = []
    for cell in cells:
        text = cell.text.strip()
        cell_contents.append(text)
    return (cell_contents)

def remove_char(string):
    import re
    string = re.sub("[A-Za-z]", "", string)
    return string

def get_fixtures(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    table = soup.find('table')
    cells = table.find_all("td")

    output = scrape(cells)

    output = np.array(output)
    output = output.reshape(21, 8)
    output = pd.DataFrame(output)
    header_row = 0
    output.columns = output.iloc[header_row]
    output = output.drop(header_row)
    output = output.reset_index(drop=True)
    output.columns = ["team", "gw1", "gw2", "gw3", "gw4", "gw5", "gw6", "total"]

    output.gw1 = output.gw1.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw1 = output.gw1.apply(float)
    output.gw2 = output.gw2.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw2 = output.gw2.apply(float)
    output.gw3 = output.gw3.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw3 = output.gw3.apply(float)
    output.gw4 = output.gw4.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw4 = output.gw4.apply(float)
    output.gw5 = output.gw5.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw5 = output.gw5.apply(float)
    output.gw6 = output.gw6.apply(remove_char)
    output.gw6 = output.gw6.apply(float)
    EG = output
    EG.total = EG.total.apply(float)
    return(EG)

EG_data = get_fixtures("https://playerdatabase247.com/include_premier_league_fixture_tracker_uusi.php?listtype=expgoals")
EG_data.name = 'Expected Goals'
ECS_data = get_fixtures("https://playerdatabase247.com/include_premier_league_fixture_tracker_uusi.php?listtype=cs")
ECS_data.name = 'Expected clean sheets'

def plot_fixture_data(df):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,8))
    fig.tight_layout()
    ax.bar(df.team, df.total, color = "firebrick")
    ax.bar(df.team, df.gw1+df.gw2+df.gw3, color = "darksalmon")
    ax.bar(df.team, df.gw1, color = "coral")
    ax.set_ylabel("{} (Upcoming gameweek, three week, and six week total)".format(df.name), size = 12)
    plt.xticks(rotation = 30)
    plt.savefig('static/images/plot_for_{}.png'.format(df.name),bbox_inches = 'tight')
    return
```

I then call functions from this file at the start of my main file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response
import pandas as pd
from GetFixtres import EG_data,ECS_data,plot_fixture_data

plot_fixture_data(EG_data)
plot_fixture_data(ECS_data)


app = Flask(__name__)
```

And then the specific page in which i try to show the image, this is the code

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}


{% block content %}

    <P> This page looks specifically at expected goals by each team over the next few weeks. </P>
    
    <img src='/static/images/plot_forExpected Goals.png'/>

{% endblock content %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated for this problem along with any advice on my program/code in general.

I have been through numerous threads on the same issue but all the tweaks recommended dont' seem to work for me. And knowing myself, its probably something small and stupid that I have overlooked so apologies in advance if it is.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use url_for as follows

```
<img src="{{url_for ('static' , filename='images/plot_forExpected Goals.png')}}">
```

also I'm not certain if this is an issue but you should consider removing the space from your picture name.

Comment: Hi there, thanks but that still doesnt seem to work. I've edited the file names to remove spaces and used the above code you have suggested (and of course adjusted that for the new file name). I now get the error: 'Could not build url for endpoint 'static/images' with values ['filename']. Did you mean 'static' instead?'

Comment: I've been messing around with it after this error. And if i move the images to the static folder itself (not within the images folder) and then use url_for just to static not to static/images then it works. Im confused to why however, so if anyone has any knowledge why that would be the case it would be greatly appreciated. I would of course rather have my images in the images folder..

Comment: im not entirely sure also but if that's the case do try 'static' , filename='images/plot_forExpected Goals.png'

Comment: Yeah, that works actually. Still no idea why but that plasters over the problem pretty nicely. Thanks a lot, much appreciated.

Comment: Great , i'd highly appreciate it if you accept my answer

Comment: I have also upvoted, but it wont show as I have less than 15 reputation unfortunately